# How can I reuse directshow components in Gstreamer (windows)

Tags: frameworks, directshow, gstreamer, multimedia

I am developing a new media playback application for Digital cinema. 
While checking the multimedia framework options, I am pretty impressed with GStreamer and would like to use it.

BUT, we already have developed some directshow filters, which we do not intend to throw away or refactor for now. The directshow filters involve in-house developed(with source code) and also purchased(without source code).

Question:
How can I reuse these components even though I switch from Directshow to Gstreamer?
Ideas and pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop your own plugin for GStreamer, which passes the control to your custom filters. Here is the [Guide](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/index.html).

Comment: I guess you meant we should develop something like the directshowvideosrc present in GStreamer.  With reference from   [link](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.gstreamer.devel)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or use an existing plugin, if it fits your needs. Or patch existing plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

IMO and I stand open to correction that doesn't make any sense at all. A DirectShow filter has been designed to fit into the DirectShow framework (the interfaces are designed for this), gstreamer is a multimedia framework with it's own set of interfaces and requirements, etc. Even if you could wrap the filters in a custom gstreamer plug-in, you would need to implement everything the DS framework provides you with, which sounds very complicated and is likely to be more work than just refactoring your DS filter in the first place. The other option of creating a DS graph inside a plug-in doesn't sound like a good idea either.

Comment: I understand that refactoring my DS filter(for which source code is available), will be the best option. But what about the other filters which we have purchased from a third party.

Comment: Also the Gstreamer feature list explicitly mentions about bridging to other multimedia frameworks. But I do not see any such reference in its documentation. Is there any documentation available regarding this?